# Confusing Jquery Filter, Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-views

I have created a calendar and i would like to have a filtering affect that is easy and user friendly. so i sent up a fast filter with Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

    var filters = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

    if (filters.length) {
      $('.alert').hide();
      $('.more').hide();
      $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        $('.alert.' + $(this).data('type')).show();
      });
    } else {
      $('.alert').show();
      $('.more').show();
    }
  });
})
```

It's very simple and dull, working with a check box of all the category's. Depending on the category's that are selected it will hide them or show them. Now this was fine until i added some Drop-Down boxes. The reason for this is the template is pretty static and will only allow 3 events within any day. So i added a 'More' option if the loop returns more than 3 events that creates a Drop-Down and displays the other events in that drop box.

[Drop-Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLEkd.png)

Now this drop-down holds events and these events will not show when i filter! i don't understand why because the 'more button' will move up the page.

[Showing Filter options and whole cal,, More Is also moved up under 2 events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l64lj.png)

When i select this more button nothing happens, it changes to 'Close' but no events show hell he drop down doesn't even show.

If i use the filter to select all the events the drop-Downs don't work so when i'm using the filter it is breaking the Drop-down. C

-- Catergory list code. I am using Django for this project.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Filter By Name<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
        <li>{% if not current_category %}<strong>{% endif %}<a href="{% url "calendar_current_month" %}">{% trans "All Employees" %}</a>{% if not current_category %}</strong>{% endif %}</li>
        {% for category in categories %}
            <li class="{{category.color}}"><div class="item" style="color:#{{category.color}};"><input name="{{category.color}}" id="{{category.color}}" data-type="{{category.color}}" type="checkbox"><label for="{{category.color}}">{{ category.name }}</label></div></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to filter or maybe a reason why this is happening,
 Thank you.

If you need anything else to help me figure this out please don't hesitate to ask. I am lost and would really appreciate any help that can be given.